# Symfony/Doctrine event listener only triggered if first of any UniTest

Tags: symfony, doctrine, event-listener

I'm encoutering a "Im going to turn mad" problem with doctrine listeners.

Quickly summed up behavior:
I need to refresh a summary of all aquired right when:

- 1 A user is created
- 2 A right is added to the user
- 3 A riht is added to a profile linked to the user
- 4 others on updates but we can trigger the bug with these use case only.

I have an event listener on thoose entities to dispatch a message to re-compute the summary.
Here's how it's setup.

```
services.yaml
    App\EventListener\DroitResume\ListenerOne:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Auth\UserAccount', method: 'postPersistUserAccount', lazy: true}
            - { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Auth\UserRight', method: 'postChangeUserRight', lazy: true}
            - { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Auth\UserProfileRight', method: 'postChangeUserProfileRight', lazy: true}
    App\EventListener\DroitResume\ListenerTwo:
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'postPersist', entity: 'App\Entity\Auth\UserAccount', method: 'postPersistUserAccount', lazy: true}
```

Second listener is here for demonstration/test purpose, usualcode only has one.

```
ListenerOne.php
class ListenerOne
{
    private MessageBusInterface $messageBus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus)
    {
        $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
    }

    public function postChangeUserRight(UserRight $userRight): void
    {
        print "ListenerOne => dispatch postChangeUserRight\n";
        $this->messageBus->dispatch(new UserRefreshResumeRightsMessage($userRight->getUserAccount()->getId()));
    }

    public function postChangeUserProfileRight(UserProfileRight $userProfileRight): void
    {
        print "ListenerOne => dispatch postChangeUserProfileRight\n";
        $this->messageBus->dispatch(new ProfileRefreshResumeRightsMessage($userProfileRight->getUserProfile()->getId()));
    }

    public function postPersistUserAccount(UserAccount $userAccount)
    {
        print "ListenerOne => dispatch postPersistUserAccount\n";
        $this->messageBus->dispatch(new UserRefreshResumeRightsMessage($userAccount->getId()));
    }
}


ListenerTwo.php
class ListenerTwo
{
    private MessageBusInterface $messageBus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus)
    {
        $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
    }

    public function postPersistUserAccount(UserAccount $userAccount)
    {
        print "ListenerTwo => dispatch postPersistUserAccount\n";
        $this->messageBus->dispatch(new UserRefreshResumeRightsMessage($userAccount->getId()));
    }
}
```

Then thoose unit tests

```
RefreshRightTest.php
class RefreshRightTest extends MyTestCase {  //MyTestCase extends KernelTestCase and add some usefull methods

    public function testPersistUserOne() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        
        $user = new UserAccount();
        $user->setName('blabla One');
        $user->setEmail('blablaone@test.com');
        print "Persist User Blabla One\n";
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $user = new UserAccount();
        $user->setName('blabla Two');
        $user->setEmail('blablatwo@test.com');
        print "Persist User Blabla Two\n";
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function testPersistUserRightOne() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $user = $this->getExistingUserFromName('Existing User One');
        
        $userRight = new UserRight();
        $userRight->setUserAccount($user);
        $userRight->setRightKey('RIGHT_ONE');
        $userRight->setValue(1);
        print "Persist UserRight One\n";
        $em->persist($userRight);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function testPersistUserTwo() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        
        $user = new UserAccount();
        $user->setName('blabla Three');
        $user->setEmail('blablathree@test.com');
        print "Persist User Blabla Three\n";
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }


    public function testPersistUserRightTwo() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $user = $this->getExistingUserFromName('Existing User Two');
        
        $userRight = new UserRight();
        $userRight->setUserAccount($user);
        $userRight->setRightKey('RIGHT_ANY');
        $userRight->setValue(2);
        print "Persist UserRight Two\n";
        $em->persist($userRight);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Here the console output when I run the tests:

```
Persist User Blabla One
ListenerOne => dispatch postPersistUserAccount
ListenerTwo => dispatch postPersistUserAccount
Persist User Blabla Two
ListenerOne => dispatch postPersistUserAccount
ListenerTwo => dispatch postPersistUserAccount
Persist UserRight One
ListenerOne => dispatch postChangeUserRight
Persist User Blabla Three
Persist UserRight Two
ListenerOne => dispatch postChangeUserRight
```

As you can see postPersistUserAccount listeners are only triggered if it's in the first test.
As soon as any other listener is triggered it never triggers again.
I can run any amount of tests on postChangeUserRight or postChangeUserProfileRight they will always trigger. But any listener on postPersistUserAccount won't trigger past first test is run.

I don't have any other listner on any of thoose entities.
I don't have any stop propagation anywhere in the code.
The only difference between entities is that UserAccout implements UserInterface (as it's my users table)

Has anyone encountered something similar before. I've tried everything I can to try and find what's happening, but nothing consistent as emerged yet.

Some exemples of test order run:

```
T1: persist UserAccount
T2: persist UserRight
T3: persist UserAccount
=> postPersistUserAccount only triggers on T1


T1: persist UserRight
T2: persist UserAccount
T3: persist UserAccount
T4: persist UserRight
=> postPersistUserAccount never triggers, postPersistUserRight triggers ont Tests 1 and 4 as intended
```

Comment: As I understand your code, in your second test you persist only `UserRight` which I suppose is the owner of the relation with the `User`. I suppose it's normal that a `User` entity Listener is not triggered since you don't modify and persist it.

Comment: My probleme is not that it's not triggered in second test, but in third where I persist a new UserAccount, that should trigger postPersistUserAccount but doesn't.